# SwiftUI - Picker inside Form

Tags: swiftui

When putting multiple elements into a Form row there is a string behaviour with the row separator.

It always start where the first Picker appears. Is it possible to change that?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct PlaygroundView: View {
  @State private var names = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
  @State private var selection: String?

  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      Form {
        Section("Section 1") {
          HStack {
            Picker("picker", selection: $selection) {
              ForEach(names, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
              }
            }
            TextField("foo", text: .constant("foo"))
            TextField("baz", text: .constant("baz"))
          }
          HStack {
            TextField("foo", text: .constant("foo"))
            Picker("picker", selection: $selection) {
              ForEach(names, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
              }
            }
            TextField("baz", text: .constant("baz"))
          }
          HStack {
            TextField("foo", text: .constant("foo"))
            TextField("baz", text: .constant("baz"))
            Picker("picker", selection: $selection) {
              ForEach(names, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
              }
            }
          }
          Text("....")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct PlaygroundView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    PlaygroundView()
  }
}
```

[image: layout]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `Picker` has its own row separators, which start at the `Picker` and go to the end of the row. Applying `.listRowSeparator(.hidden)` has no effect, you can't turn them off.

What you can do, is turn on separators for the whole row by applying `.listRowSeparator(.visible)` to the `HStack`, but this doesn't help much because the separator for the `Picker` is applied too, so the extra thickness is noticeable.

As a clumsy workaround, you can put a hidden `Picker` at the start of the row and then move the `HStack` to an overlay:

```swift
Form {
  Section("Section 1") {
    HStack {
      // as before
    }
    Picker("Dummy", selection: .constant(0)) { Text(".").tag(0) }
      .hidden()
      .overlay {
        HStack {
          // as before
        }
      }
    Picker("Dummy", selection: .constant(0)) { Text(".").tag(0) }
      .hidden()
      .overlay {
        HStack {
          // as before
        }
      }
    Text("....")
  }
}
```

[image: Pickers]

Answer (score 0):

When using `.labelsHidden()` on the Picker, the border is displayed proper. If you don't need the label, this solves the problem.

```swift
Picker("picker", selection: $selection) {
  ForEach(names, id: \.self) {
    Text($0)
  }
}
.labelsHidden()
```